# Get website name using TypoScript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Is there a way to get the website name using TypoScript?

In my TypoScript template I am using

```
data = page : name
```

to get the name of the current page I am on e.g. `About`.

I need to get the webiste name as well, so I have tried

```
data = site : name
```

but this is not correct and I can't find the correct data name for the website name in the documentation.

NOTE: by website name I mean the `Sitename` entered in the template settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With line below you need to know used uid of the TypoScript template entry from table *sys_template*, where uid=1 in example below:

```
data = DB:sys_template:1:title
```

Or maybe you want use the sitename as set for your installation:

```
data = GLOBAL:TYPO3_CONF_VARS|SYS|sitename
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution on http://www.sk-typo3.de/Seitentitel-aendern.58.0.html from Waldgeist. It reads from the TSFE without a DB query.

```
  lib.siteTitle = TEXT
  lib.siteTitle{
    data = TSFE:tmpl|sitetitle
    attribute = property
  }
```