# How to use Sitename in Constants as a default value in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, constants, typoscript

I want to set the Sitename in Constants by default, so I can use this settings.variable in my Fluidtemplate.

I found in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42434429/get-website-name-using-typoscript) here on stackoverflow:

- DB:sys_template|1|title
- GLOBAL:TYPO3_CONF_VARS|SYS|sitename

But if I use this in my constants.ts like this:

```
# cat=plugin.tx_rmnavigation/01_NaviSettings/a; type=string; label=testing sitetitle
testsitetitle = DB:sys_template|1|title
```

OR

```
# cat=plugin.tx_rmnavigation/01_NaviSettings/a; type=string; label=testing sitetitle
testsitetitle = GLOBAL:TYPO3_CONF_VARS|SYS|sitename
```

AND in my setup.ts:

```
testsitetitle = {$plugin.tx_rmnavigation.settings.testsitetitle}
```

I get only the text not the value of the "variable" see this picture [Constant Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnlFS.jpg)...

How can I use the Sitename in Constants as a defaultvalue?

### Edit

I forgot to say, perhaps it's important for this issue, I try this here in both files:

```
plugin.tx_rmnavigation {
    settings {
        ..
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign your constant to a content object's data property (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/ContentObjects/Index.html and https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html#data) to get it resolved:

```
testsitetitle = TEXT
testsitetitle.data = {$plugin.tx_rmnavigation.settings.testsitetitle}
```

And I would prefer your second variant for the constant definition because it uses the value from the current template record:

```
# cat=plugin.tx_rmnavigation/01_NaviSettings/a; type=string; label=testing sitetitle
testsitetitle = GLOBAL:TYPO3_CONF_VARS|SYS|sitename
```

But the first one should also work if you use colons instead of pipes:

```
testsitetitle = DB:sys_template:1:title
```

Comment: as far as I can see from the documentation the gettext DB uses colons and not pipes - see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/DataTypes/Gettext/Index.html#db

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi you're right, will append the corrected constant

Answer (score 2):

If you have a multi domain page the query to DB:sys_template:1:sitetitle might not work, as the 1 is the UID, not the PID of the root node of your template. But TSFE to the rescue!

In the context of your page call, the TSFE already has the sitetitle from the backend template loaded.

If you for example want to output a og:site_name, you can access the value by using:

```
og:site_name = TEXT
og:site_name {
    data = TSFE:tmpl|sitetitle
    attribute = property
}
```

This way no additional database queries are needed and it will work on multi domain, multi root node pages.

Comment: This is by far the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your suggestions. I found a solution with your infos.

---

Honestly I think this doesn't works in Constants, because the both methods are readonly.

So I found a working solution for my Issue: I need that Variable only for read in my Templates, so I create a new Typoscript File `libs.ts` and included this with:

```
# Include Libraries
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE: EXT:rm_navigation/Resources/Private/TypoScript/libs.ts">
```

in the `/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.ts` File.

The content of `libs.ts` is:

#### TSFE-Syntax

```
lib.sitename = TEXT
lib.sitename.data = GLOBAL:TYPO3_CONF_VARS|SYS|sitename
```

OR

#### DB-Syntax

```
lib.sitename = TEXT
lib.sitename.data = DB:sys_template:1:sitetitle
```

works both. I read that you use the **colon-syntax for DB usage** and the **pipe-syntax for Global Variables**.

To get this to Fluid use this Code:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.sitename" />
```

I hope it helps Others who also has this Issue.